# Inline-block divs behave weird when content is added to them

Tags: javascript, html, css

Doubts

1. When content is added to a div, why does it move down, (shown in image)
2. When content is added to all the three divs, they become normal and comes to their top position

[image]

```css
div{
              background-color:orange;
              height: 200px;
              width: 200px;
              display:inline-block;
            }
```

```html
<html>
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8" />
              <title>Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div class="div1">ankur</div>
              <div class="div2"></div>
              <div class="div1"></div>
              <br>
              <button value="prev">Prev</button>
              <button value="next">Next</button>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: try vertical aline

Comment: this is duplicate but cannot find

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align:top;` to the div CSS

```css
div{
  background-color:orange;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1">ankur</div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <br>
  <button value="prev">Prev</button>
  <button value="next">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That helped but why does this happen in the first place ?

Comment: Because the default `vertical-align` value of an `inline-block` element is `baseline`. You can [read more about it here](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/).

Answer (score 1):

The default `vertical-align` value for inline elements is `baseline` which is what causes what you're seeing. When you add text to all your divs, then they're aligned because of this.